# Como limitar uma conexão JDBC a fazer apenas consultas "select"?

Tags: sql, jdbc

Gostaria que minha conexão JDBC não fizesse consultas que possam fazer mudanças nas tabelas (insert, delete, update, drop). Tem alguma maneira disso ser feito?

Comment: Acho que é mais simples criar um usuário que tenha permissão apenas para consultas na database.

Comment: Qual banco está usando?

Comment: Verdade @rray, é melhor mesmo criar um usuário no BD com acesso a consultas apenas

Answer (score 1):

RebeccaMM,

- Primeiro crie um novo usuário no seu banco de dados
- Dê a esse usuário apenas as permissões necessárias, no seu caso apenas **`SELECT`**

Utilize o seguinte código para executar as operações acima:

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT CONNECT TO username;
GRANT SELECT no schema.table TO username;
```

E use o nome de usuário/senha criado acima ao obter a conexão JDBC. 
Se outras partes do aplicativo precisam inserir, excluir ou atualizar, eles podem usar outra conexão, configurada com as permissões necessárias. Como você não informou seu banco de dados verifique o código compatível para essas operações.

Espero que isso ajude...

Boa Sorte!